# How to disable user registration for the default subscriber user role?

Tags: user-registration, signup

I'm dealing with fake user registrations on my site. Since i'm using WooCommerce, i have a custom signup page which will generate users with **"customer"** as the user role. However, all of the fake users are registering through wp-login.php, which will generate a user with the **"subscriber"** role.

Is it possible to somehow disable the user generation process(probably inside `wp_insert_user()`) if it tries to signup a user with the role set to subscriber? The closest action i could find is `user_register`, which triggers immediately after the user has been created, so i could delete the user if the role is subscriber, but i would like to do this before the user is even created.

Also most of the user data is filtered, but not the user role:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be more elegant way to do it, but from quick look at the code it seems quite easy to simply override the relevant option on login page:

```
add_action( 'login_init', function () {
    add_action( 'pre_option_users_can_register', '__return_null' );
} );
```